# How to set 'X-Robots-Tag' of my sitemap.xml with Express

Tags: node.js, express

How can I set the HTTP-header 'X-Robots-Tag' of my sitemap.xml (and only this file) to 'noindex, follow' with express ?

The sitemap.xml is located a the root of my app.

Here is a snippet of my exress config :

express/development.js

```
const express = require('express')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const cors = require('cors')
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
const webpackHotServerMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-server-middleware')
const config = require('./../webpack/webpack.development.config.js')

const app = express()
const compiler = webpack(config)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('build'))
app.use(express.static('public'))

...
```

I've tried this :

```
... 

app.get('/sitemap.xml', res => {
  res.setHeader('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex, follow')
})
```

and this:

```
app.get('/sitemap.xml', res => {
  res.set('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex, follow')
})
```

Also, how can I see if the header has been updated.

I've tried : `$curl -v localhost:3000/sitemap.xml`

But there is no 'X-Robots-Tag' in the header so I assume it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html), the static middleware accepts an options argument in which you can set the `setHeaders` function to modify response headers based on the path:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const express = require('express');

const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');

// the following creates and a public directory in the script directory and populates it with some files (for the sake of this demo).

// create the public directory if it doesn't exist
if (!fs.existsSync(publicDirectoryPath)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(publicDirectoryPath);
}

// create a sample sitemap.xml (for the sake of this demo)
const siteMapXml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>`;
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(publicDirectoryPath, './sitemap.xml'), siteMapXml);

// create a sample index.html
const indexHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <p>It works!</p>
</html>`;
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(publicDirectoryPath, './index.html'), indexHtml);

// setup and start the express server

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), {
    setHeaders: (res, path) => {
      if (path.endsWith("sitemap.xml")) {
        res.setHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "noindex, follow");
      }
    }
  })
);

app.listen(PORT);

// check response headers

const makeGetRequestAndPrintHeaders = (path) => {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: PORT,
    path,
    method: 'GET'
  };

  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`GET ${path}`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 2));
  });

  req.end();
}

makeGetRequestAndPrintHeaders('/index.html');
makeGetRequestAndPrintHeaders('/sitemap.xml');

// example output
/*
GET /index.html                                     
{                                                   
  "x-powered-by": "Express",                        
  "accept-ranges": "bytes",                         
  "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",             
  "last-modified": "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 14:28:26 GMT", 
  "etag": "W/\"6b-168e74243aa\"",                   
  "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",       
  "content-length": "107",                          
  "date": "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 14:28:26 GMT",          
  "connection": "close"                             
}                                                   
GET /sitemap.xml                                    
{                                                   
  "x-powered-by": "Express",                        
  "x-robots-tag": "noindex, follow",                
  "accept-ranges": "bytes",                         
  "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",             
  "last-modified": "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 14:28:26 GMT", 
  "etag": "W/\"113-168e74243a9\"",                  
  "content-type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",        
  "content-length": "275",                          
  "date": "Wed, 13 Feb 2019 14:28:26 GMT",          
  "connection": "close"                             
}
*/
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. But, as mentioned in my first post, I'm not sure how I should check if the header has been correctly updated. Any help on that as well ?

Comment: @BaptisteF. I've modified my answer and added a fully working example. The code above will create a directory named **public** in script directory and writes an `index.html` file as well as a `sitemap.xml` file in that directory. Then it sends two HTTP GET requests to the listening express server and logs the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

You're actually setting headers for the request, the below code should work:

```js
app.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Robots-Tag', 'noindex, follow')
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/sitemap.xml`)
})
```

for `app.get`, the callback function has three arguments:

```js
app.get('/sitemap.xml', (request, response, nextHandler) => {})
```

`request` is the request object which, comes from the client.

`response` is the response that you'll send from the server, which is what you actually want to change.

`nextHandler` passes everything on to your next request handler, by calling it (`nextHandler()`)